# How to send parameters values to .cs file to entity designer.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In **TaskReportPage.aspx** page I have *startdate, enddate, dropdown* and one download button.

The code looks like this:

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter The Details To Download Report</legend>
    <div class="label">
        Start Date :<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStartDate" />
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        End Date:
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEndDate"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        Employee Name:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="AllRecords">All Records</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btndisplay" runat="server" Text="View Report" OnClick="btndisplay_Click">
        </asp:Button>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Download" align="center" Text="Download" OnClick="Download_Click">
        </asp:Button>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="color: Red"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

In **TaskReportPage.aspx.cs** file I can get values from **TaskReportPage.aspx** page.

In Back end I have a table with these columns:

```
Description varchar(500),
CreatedDate datetime,
StatusId int,
UserId int,
Hour int,
Day varchar(10)
```

I have written a stored procedure for retriving the values from the database which looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RetriveDatatable]  
(  
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @Dropdown varchar(50),
    @ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    SELECT Day, t.CreatedDate, Description, Hour, Firstname
    FROM tbl_TaskType t, tbl_UserDetails u
    WHERE t.CreatedDate BETWEEN '@StartDate' AND '@EndDate'
    AND u.ID=(SELECT ID FROM tbl_UserDetails WHERE FirstName=@Dropdown);
END
```

Im Importing this stored procedure in  **Eye1.designer.cs** file:

This file is follwing the entity framework procedure.

It will look like:

```
public int RetriveDatatable(Nullable<global::System.Int32> userID, Nullable<global::System.DateTime> startDate, Nullable<global::System.DateTime> endDate, global::System.String dropdown = dropdowntParameter1)
{
    ObjectParameter userIDParameter;
    if (userID.HasValue)
    {
        userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID);
    }
    else
    {
        userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(global::System.Int32));
    }

    ObjectParameter startDateParameter;
    if (startDate.HasValue)
    {
        startDateParameter = new ObjectParameter("StartDate", startDate);
    }
    else
    {
        startDateParameter = new ObjectParameter("StartDate", typeof(global::System.DateTime));
    }

    ObjectParameter endDateParameter;
    if (endDate.HasValue)
    {
        endDateParameter = new ObjectParameter("EndDate", endDate);
    }
    else
    {
        endDateParameter = new ObjectParameter("EndDate", typeof(global::System.DateTime));
    }

    ObjectParameter dropdowntParameter;
    if (dropdown != null)
    {
        dropdowntParameter = new ObjectParameter("Dropdown", dropdown);
    }
    else
    {
        dropdowntParameter = new ObjectParameter("Dropdown", typeof(global::System.String));
    }

    return base.ExecuteFunction("RetriveDatatable", userIDParameter,startDateParameter, endDateParameter, dropdowntParameter);
}
```

Finally my problem is that I want to send the *startdate,enddate and dropdown* parameter values from **TaskReportPage.aspx.cs** page to **eye1.disigner.cs** file page. Then it will call the SP and I get data from database to **TaskReportPage.aspx.cs**.

Please Help me Out.......

Answer (score 0):

You should not be editing ANY code in the designer file - it is generated and used solely by visual studio and will eventually be overwritten and you will lose your manual changes. Please move all the code you've added to the designer file into your aspx.cs file.